# Calculating index of a subgroup of possibly infinite group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. And $A$ and $B$  are subgroups. I know that $|G:A|$ and $|B : A|$ are finite. Can I can conclude that $|G:A| / |B : A|$ equals $|G:B|$?

That is, can I use normal cancellation rules here?

Comment: Are $A$ and $B$ subgroups of $G$?

Comment: @Servaes yes, they are

Comment: The answer is yes. Just look at the cosets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is correct. Since $|G:A|$ is finite you can manipulate any index for any subgroup lying between $A$ and $G$.

Comment: Ok, could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: In general, $|G:A|=|G:B| \cdot |B:A|$, even for infinite cardinals. This can be shown by considering cosets, and is standard group theory knowledge, which should be in whatever textbook you use.